# Can Selenium talk to IEDriver on a custom port?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, phantomjs, codeception

I know that I can launch multiple instances of IEDriverServer.exe on the same machine, as long as I give each instance a unique "--port" argument.

What I don't know is how to tell a Selenium Server instance to look for one of the IEDriverServer instances on the custom port.  The only port arguments I see available for the Selenium startup is the port that Selenium itself listens on.  Since I *can* tell the Selenium Server instance where to find the IEDriverServer executable, via "-Dwebdriver.ie.driver" property argument, I was hoping for something similar for IE driver server *port*.  But I cannot find such an option.

My *last resort* thought was perhaps the "capabilities" arguments (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities), but nothing shown there looks promising.  I see that the Firefox driver has a port option (webdriver_firefox_port), but it seems to be the only browser with such an option.

NOTE:  the same question could be asked regarding PhantomJS instead of IEServerDriver... I see no way to tell Selenium that a PhantomJS instance has been started separately on a custom port.

Comment: Would this be a situation where the Selenium Grid would solve your use case?

Comment: The only way Grid could help my case here would be if the grid's nodes were all on separate machines, and thus each node could simply talk to the one IEDriverServer instance on the node (on its default port).  That would require multiple WIndows machines/VMs, which is cost prohibitive for my case.

Comment: Well if you can register multiple IEDrivers on different ports to a Grid that might live on the same machine as the IEDrivers, i would assume the Grid would be able to handle the port differences without any custom port changes inside your code. You would just connect to the Grid, requesting a new ie driver and it handles talking to the different ports

Comment: I'd also add that it looks like running multiple instances of the IEdriver on the same machine isn't well supported/tested, so you may run into other issues with it https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#multiple-instances-of-internetexplorerdriver

Comment: That's what I started with.  Multiple nodes under a single hub, where the nodes were on the same Windows machine but being run by different user accounts.  I was not manually starting the IEDriverServer separately for any of the nodes.  But since the driver, when launched by the Selenium node, defaults to port 5555, only the first launched instance would function, thus leaving the other nodes unable to run IE tests due to the port collision.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that "not well tested" scenario description.  It seemed to imply multiple IE instances side by side, which I interpreted as "in the same user session".  I was trying to avoid that by running the individual Selenium nodes under different user accounts, thus segregating the IE instances from each other over the user account boundaries.

Comment: But unless the IEDriverServer instances can be launched on different ports, there's no way to see if that user account boundary can keep the IE instances from affecting each other.  However, since plain old users on the same Windows server can manually use IE without colliding with each other, I would hope the IEs launched by IEDriverServers in different user account sessions would also be protected from each other.